# Typescript/Javascript: Get object attribute from string parameter?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why does this code not work and how do I do it instead?

```
interface inter {
    first: string;
    second: number;
    third: string[];
}
let test: inter = {
    first: "first thing",
    second: 52,
    third: ["ZERO", "ONE", "TWO"],
}
let attr: string = "second"// ||"third"||"first"
console.log("> "+test[`${attr}`])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide enough information to TS for it to know that `test` has a property of `attr` you can look up. So, type `attr` not as a string, but as `keyof inter` - and also use plain bracket notation instead of wrapping the property lookup in an unnecessary template literal:

```
interface inter {
    first: string;
    second: number;
    third: string[];
}
let test: inter = {
    first: "first thing",
    second: 52,
    third: ["ZERO", "ONE", "TWO"],
}
let attr: keyof inter = "second"
console.log("> " + test[attr])
```

Another option is to declare `attr` with `const` and avoid the explicit type annotation - since `'second'` gets assigned to it, it'll be typed as `'second'`, not `string`:

```
const attr = "second"
console.log("> " + test[attr])
```

Comment: What if the interface is unknown and injected or the attribute const has to be changed?

Comment: Also, the keyof variable must be a string literal and defeats the purpose of having it be a variable in the first place.

Comment: If the shape of the object is dynamic, you can use generics and extract the value inside a function: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwin0OrOsMfuAhUNWa0KHS51CbQQFjAAegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.typescriptlang.org%2Fdocs%2Fhandbook%2Fgenerics.html&usg=AOvVaw1LHVA8NPdl-r11gwf7mxGg If the object is not only dynamic but completely unknown, TS can't really help you at all.  (but that situation should be quite rare)